# Is it possible to call to APIs inside a react-router loader function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'd like to know if it's possible to make 2 API calls inside a loader function if I am using react-router 6. My ideas was to create an object based on  these 2 calls and destruct the object in the rendering component like  this:

```
function MainComponent (){
const {data , reservation} = useRouteLoaderData('room-details');
..
..
}
export default MainComponent;

export async function loader({request, params}) {

    const id = params.roomId;
    const response = await fetch ('http://localhost:8080/rooms/' + id);
    const response2 = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/rooms/reservation/' + id)

    const megaResponse = {
        data: response,  //i tried data:{respose} It ain't work 
        reservation: response2,
    };
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw json({message: 'Something Wrong'}, {status: 500});
    }
    else {        
        return megaResponse; 
    }
}
```

But i have no success output.
I'd really want to make these 2 call in one place, otherwise I will have to use useEffect in a child component. Not a good Idea I think.
Thanks

Comment: I see no reason why you can't make more than one network request here. What is the issue or problem? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: Hi, the problem is that whenever I want to use a property, eg: data.room or simply data i got undefined or [object Response] respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I tried it and it worked. It is as follow:

```
function MainComponent (){
const [data , reservation] = useRouteLoaderData('room-details');
..
..
}
export default MainComponent;

export async function loader({request, params}) {

    const id = params.roomId;

    return Promise.all([
        fetch ('http://localhost:8080/rooms/' + id),
            fetch('http://localhost:8080/rooms/reservation/' + id)
    ])
    .then(
        ([data, reservation]) =>
        Promise.all([data.json(), reservation.json()]), 
        error => {throw json({message: 'Something Wrong'}, {status: 500});}
    )
    .then(([data, reservation]) => {
        return [data, reservation];
    });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not returning the unpacked response, i.e. JSON. I suggest surrounding the asynchronous code in a `try/catch` and simply try to process the requests/responses. Unpack the JSON value from the response objects. Since it doesn't appear the requests are dependent on one another I recommend loading them into an array of Promises that can be run concurrently and awaited as a whole. If during any part of the processing a Promise is rejected or an exception thrown, the `catch` block will return the JSON error response to the UI, otherwise, the `{ data, reservation }` object is returned.

```js
const loader = async ({ request, params }) => {
  const { roomId } = params;

  try {
    const [data, reservation] = await Promise.all([
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/rooms/" + roomId),
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/rooms/reservaton/" + roomId)
    ]).then((responses) => responses.map((response) => response.json()));
    return { data, reservation };
  } catch {
    throw json({ message: "Something Wrong" }, { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

[image: Edit is-it-possible-to-call-to-apis-inside-a-react-router-loader-function]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I dunno why I am not getting the response from the API calls. They are still pending. I tried them on the BE with swagger and postman, everything is going well in the BE. I've got this error in the debugger ![Error in the debugger](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gorostiaga/Images/main/Screenshot%20from%202023-02-10%2011-14-44.png)

Comment: @Gorostiaga Are you setting a breakpoint right at the line where the Promise chain is started? If you continue to step through the code do they eventually settle? This issue appears to be unrelated to the topic of your post here regarding making multiple fetch requests in the action callback. Based on your screenshot I'd say we've accomplished at least that much. Could you try commenting out that action code entirely and make just a single `fetch` request to see how it resolves?

Comment: @Gorostiaga It may be more valuable to create a new SO post regarding this issue with making 
the individual requests. If you do create a new post then feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to the new post and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found the solutions and I posted. Cheers

Comment: @Gorostiaga Interesting, there shouldn't be much of any difference between using `async/await` and `try/catch`, and using a Promise chain. Glad you got it sorted out.